# Replicate univariable poisson regression results from a single-row-per-patient dataset on a multiple-row-per-patient dataset

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, poisson-regression

I performed univariable Poisson regression on a dataset of individuals where each individual had one row of data.  The variable Sex, for example, had the incidence rate ratio 2.11 (95% CI 1.73-2.56, p<0.001) for male vs. female, and was produced with code of the form `model <- glm(Event ~ as.factor(Sex) + offset(log(Person-Years)), family = "poisson", data = single-row-per-patient.dataset)`.

Now I want to include a time-dependent variable, which would mean each (or most) individual(s) having multiple rows of data.  However, I want to be able to replicate my univariable results on this dataset.  When I run the same code as above, though, but with `data = multiple-row-per-patient.dataset` I get the incidence rate ratio 2.02 (95% CI 1.86-2.20, p<0.001) - I'm assuming since the regression is taking each row as a separate individual, and thus the power is increased, hence the tighter confidence interval.

A colleague suggested I try `model <- glm(Event ~ as.factor(Sex) + offset(log(Person-Years)) + (1|IndividualID), family = "poisson", data = single-row-per-patient.dataset)` including the `(1|IndividualID)` as a way of telling the model to treat each indivduals' sex as a single input, regardless of how many rows of data they actually have in the new multiple-row-per-patient dataset, but I get the same result: 2.02 (95% CI 1.86-2.20, p<0.001). The estimates for the `(1|IndividualID)` term are all NAs though so I'm not sure if I'm including it correctly...

Does anyone know how, if possible at all, I can replicate my univariable results from the single-row-per-individual dataset on the multiple-row-per-patient dataset?

Many thanks